# Definition of the Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I've seen a few different definitions of the transform going from $f(t)$ to $F(\omega)$ with a bunch of $2\pi$s or $\sqrt{2\pi}$s thrown around, each giving different results. Same thing happens with the $\delta$ function, with WolframAlpha saying it is the Fourier Transform of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, which means $\delta(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-it\omega}dt$, but as stated on some other sources, the Dirac Delta is defined as $\delta(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{+ikx}dx$. Also according to WolframAlpha, the forward and inverse transforms of $1$ are equal to the same thing, which would imply that $e^{-i\omega t}=e^{+i\omega t}$. These results have me very confused and it would be ideal if someone can give me a general form for the transform and the Dirac Delta, and it'd be even better if someone could explain to me why Wolfram gives the above results.

Comment: Forward and backward transforms of $1$ are the same according to that definition but this does not imply that $e^{-i\omega t}=e^{i\omega t}$. Instead it implies that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}1\cdot e^{-i\omega t}\,dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}1\cdot e^{i\omega t}\,dt$$ which is clearly true by using the transformation $t\mapsto -t$

Comment: I’m sorry, could you explain in a little more detail about why this is true? Thanks

Comment: What I wrote has the definition of the forward Fourier transform of $1$ on one side, and the backward Fourier transform on the other side. So to say the forward and backward transforms are the same is the same as saying that those two integrals are equal. To verify why they are equal, substitute $u=-t$ into the integral on the right and you'll get $$-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\int_{+\infty}^{-\infty}1\cdot e^{-i\omega u}\,du=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}1\cdot e^{-i\omega u}\,du$$ which is now exactly the same as the other side.

Comment: We have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x') e^{i\omega x'}{\rm d}x']e^{-i\omega x}{\rm d}\omega = 2\pi f(x)$ so if we define $\mathcal{F}[f] = A\int f(x)e^{i\omega x}{\rm d}x$ and $\mathcal{F}^{-1}[f] = B\int f(\omega) e^{-i\omega x}{\rm d}x$ then we would need $AB = 1/(2\pi)$ in order for $\mathcal{F}^{-1}[\mathcal{F}[f]] \equiv f$. This is what leads to the different conventions (some like $A=1,B=1/[2\pi]$, some like $A=1/[2\pi],B=1$ and some like the symmetric one $A=B=1/\sqrt{2\pi}$).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Wolfram probably has too much influence in mathematics but, in my opinion, Wolfram's style is good in this instance. If you are unsure, I would recommend the style of Fourier transform in which, as you say, $\delta(\omega)=(1/\sqrt{2\pi})\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-it\omega}\,dt$. The reason is that this style [a] lets you work naturally in radians and [b] maintains natural symmetry between the transform and its inverse. Alternate Fourier styles are used by some authors for various reasons but fail either [a] or [b].

Comment: $$\delta(\omega)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-it\omega}\,dt$$ Is of course not true : the integral diverges for every $\omega$. What is true is that **in the sense of distributions** $\delta$ is the Fourier transform of  the constant function $f(t)= 1$. But for non-integrable functions as $f$, the Fourier transform isn't defined by an integral. However, it is true that $$1 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(t) e^{i \omega t}dt$$ here the Fourier transform can be defined by an integral because $\delta$ is a compactly supported distribution. @JohnDoe

Answer (score 2):

The factors $2\pi$ (and possible roots of them) are just a convention and sadly enough there a lot of different conventions. As for the choice of a minus sign in the exponential function, this is again a convention.

Comment: This means applying the transform with a different convention would give a different answer, right?

Comment: Yes indeed. So it is important to give the convention you used.